# Unity C#: change scenes by reading callback Boolean inside voide Update()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Struggling with a specific thing here. I need to change scenes when the calibration is successful. For that, I can use:

```
if (someVariable == true)
{
   SceneManager.LoadScene("MainScene");
}
```

The code that calls the calibration start is this:

```
private void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(_startKey))
            {
                var calibrationStartResult = StartCalibration(
                    resultCallback: (calibrationResult) =>
                        Debug.Log("Calibration was " + (calibrationResult ? "successful" : "unsuccessful"))
                );

                Debug.Log("Calibration " + (calibrationStartResult ? "" : "not ") + "started");
            }
        }
```

I need a way to use that **resultCallback** inside the **private void Update()** in order to change scenes, because **resultCallback** returns either true or false, if the calibration of my VR system was successful. Also, here's what **StartCalibration()** returns:

```
public bool StartCalibration(Vector3[] points = null, System.Action<bool> resultCallback = null)
```

Q: How do I code this to use the boolean value of resultCallback to change the scene? So far it writes to the console whatever the result was, but I don't really need that output, if I can make it change scene automatically.

I'm not very experienced in C#.

I've tried the following, but, of course, it doesn't work:

```
private void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(_startKey))
            {
                var calibrationStartResult = StartCalibration(
                    resultCallback: (calibrationResult) =>
                        Debug.Log("Calibration was " + (calibrationResult ? "successful" : "unsuccessful"))
            if (calibrationResult == true)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("MainScene");
            }
                );

                Debug.Log("Calibration " + (calibrationStartResult ? "" : "not ") + "started");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does ` it doesn't work` mean exactly? Any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it -- the key is to define a second class-level property that persists the local value. Note I'm renaming `calibrationResult` to `calibrated` for ease of use. Try:

```
bool calibrated = false;
bool startedCalibration = false;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(_startKey) && !startedCalibration)
    {
        startedCalibration = true;
        StartCalibration(
            resultCallback: (calibrated) =>
            {
                startedCalibration = false;
                print("Calibration was " + (calibrated ? "successful" : "unsuccessful");

                // Assign the local scope variable to the class property:
                this.calibrated = calibrated;
            }
        );
    }

    if (calibrated)
    {
        calibrated = false;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainScene");
    }
}
```

Another way to achieve this would be to just call `SceneManager.LoadScene` from within the resultCallback scope. This would also save on the repeat bool check of `calibrated` inside the Update. While a single Update check isn't lagging, you want to generally keep track of how much needed and unneeded things you do in these eternal loops. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Phillip. Sorry for the late response. This worked 100%. Thank you.